# mongoose Single array in update if not exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
model
state: [ {
        type: String,
        require: true
    }]

states = ['Gujarat','Rajasthan'];
state.findOneAndupdate({'_id':id},{state:states});
```

how can I update if exist override;

i want store in model is

```
states:['Gujarat','Rajstan','Amreli']
```

Comment: Please add some details to your question.

Comment: add some model detail please answer me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array field update (uniquely) in mongodb can be achieved using [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) with [`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#addtoset-modifiers) modifier:

Query:

```
let states = ["Gujarat", "Rajasthan"];

db.state.update({ _id: id }, { $addToSet: { state: { $each: states } } });
```

Comment: Thanks, you save my time. contact no 9033325096 whatsapp